# Mercurial revision/revset for unpushed changesets

Tags: mercurial

What's the best way to specifiy a revision/revset for -r options that includes your unpushed changesets, this is useful for example to clone locally or create a bookmark in a repo with only changesets that have been pushed.

This is often needed when you need to switch to working on something else in the middle of work that you are not ready to push.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few revsets that can be used to get this information:

1. `first(outgoing())` will refer to the first changeset that has not been pushed to your default push location.
2. `first(!public())` will refer to the first changeset that has not been pushed anywhere.

You might want to combine these with the `p1([set])` predicate if you want to update to the parent of those changesets to start a new anonymous branch for your new fix.

Also, before you start work on the fix, you might want to set the phase of the changesets of the unfinished work to be `secret` to prevent them from being accidentally pushed.

You can do this using `hg phase --secret --force -r "!public()"` and use `hg phase --draft -r "secret()"` to switch them back again (although this would change **all** secret changesets to draft so you'd need to be more specific if you use phases on other branches)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want the equivalent of `git stash`, this is implemented as an extension on mercurial.

Check out the wiki page. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension

EDIT: I have to mention, I don't use this workflow, in your case I would make a "dev" branch and commit regularly (even WIP commits), when stable you can merge to master.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **revset(s)**, you have to use `outgoing([path])` (or `! outgoing([path])` as changesets specification.

[path] is URL of the repository (or alias???), if not default